# Modifying Search Results for custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

i've registered a custom post type (plugin_course) and have set this up to have its own meta data.

when i go to do a search on the plugin_course edit page (/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=plugin_course) i want to be able to totally change the search results.

i cant even get the basics right. i'm fairly sure that i should use the pre_get_posts hook to return results, but even if i just want to display all the plugin_course (regardless of the search term) items it doesnt work?

```
function course_search_filter($query) {
    if (is_search() && is_main_query()) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 10);
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'plugin_course');
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Url:

```
/wp-admin/edit.php?s=test&post_status=all&post_type=plugin_course&action=-1&m=0&paged=1&mode=list&action2=-1
```

is this right? why isn't it showing the plugin_course posts?

This function works, but of course doesnt show the my custom post types:

```
function course_search_filter($query) {
    if (is_search() && is_main_query()) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 10);
        $query->set('post_type', get_post_types(array( 'public'=>true)));
        return $query;
    }
}
```

i have the custom post type linking with other custom post types, so eventually i would be writing a function to sort and filter my plugin_course post types and need to be able to return a new array of objects to be displayed in the search results. is there a way to do this?

=====

## UPDATED:

Just in case someone else wants to try and use this. The way I resolved this was to:

- Run a query and do whatever custom filtering to remove Posts I do not need in the course_search_filter function. Then added only the post ids of the items I do want into an Array.
- Unset the Search Term parameter
- Made sure to use the post_type to only show the custom post types i need
- use post__in which will only display the posts IDs

  ```
  unset($query->query_vars['s']); // unset search term
  $query->set('post_type', 'plugin_course'); // display post type
  $query->set('post__in', $post_ids); // display only items that have a match
  ```
- Added some JS to fix the Search Results label:

  ```
  var term = $("#post-search-input").val();
  $('#wpbody-content span.subtitle').show().html('Search results for “'+term+'”')
  ```

Comment: In what way do you want to "totally change the search results"? Also, your URL example is searching for custom post type plugin_course instances that include "test" in the content. If there are none that do, the result will be empty.

Comment: this is true. its better to cut this variable out totally then i can display whatever posts i wanted. see amendments to this post above